# JIRA CLI Commandline Not Authenticating With Password Federation

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I'm having a few problems getting this JIRA commandline to work:

> C:\tools\atlassian-cli-7.8.0>jira.bat --debug --verbose --options
>   basicAuthentication --server "https://jira01.COMPANY.com" --user
>   FIRST.LAST@COMPANY.COM --password PASSWORD --action getServerInfo

It connects to the JIRA server, but gives this error:

> org.swift.common.cli.CliClient$RemoteDisallowedException: User
>   'FIRST.LAST@COMPANY.COM' is not allowed to log in at this point in
>   time perhaps due to CAPTCHA requirements or too many failed login
>   requests.

This error always occurs despite the fact:

- JIRA Web > Profile > Username is what I'm using to log in.
- JIRA Web >
  Profile > Groups is jira-software-users
- The password provided to the
  commandline is indeed the one that works when I login via the web.
- I
  have tried this both with and without --options basicAuthentication
- This occurs regardless of how many times I successfully log out / log
  in to the JIRA web UI.
- Whenever I go to JIRA Web > Profile > Change
  Password, it says: "Too many incorrect login attempts: Please log out
  and log in again to access this function." (This also occurs
  regardless of how many times I successfully log out / log in to the
  JIRA web UI.)
- A CAPTCHA is never shown on the JIRA Web UI's login.

NOTE: When we login to JIRA web ui, our company appears to defer to
   federated authentication via "https://login.microsoftonline.com" into
   which we provide the credentials we're providing the script, which
   then takes us into JIRA.

**Questions:**

- How to get the commandline tool / jira server to accept the same credentials the jira web ui does?
- Is this a permissions issue or something involving the password federation?
- Suggestions for how to get this to work?
- How to get it to actually clear the "too many incorrect logins" issue?

**Cheers & Thanks!
-Roberto**

**Full trace of command is:**

> URL requested:
>   https://jira01.COMPANY.com/rest/org.swift.jira.cli/latest/validatelicense
>   Request type: GET Content type: application/json options:
>   basicauthentication URL requested:
>   https://jira01.COMPANY.com/rest/auth/1/session Request type: POST
>   Content type: application/json Using basic authentication. Request
>   property X-Atlassian-Token, value: [no-check] Request property
>   Content-Language, value: [en-US] Request property Content-Type, value:
>   [application/json] json: {} Problem determination - response: 403:
>   null Problem determination - response url:
>   https://jira01.COMPANY.com/rest/auth/1/session Problem determination -
>   request url: https://jira01.COMPANY.com/rest/auth/1/session Problem
>   determination - response data:
>
> Forbidden (403)
>
> ...
>
> Remote error: User 'FIRST.LAST@COMPANY.COM' is not allowed to log in
>   at this point in time perhaps due to CAPTCHA requirements or too many
>   failed login requests. Go to the user interface and login to clear the
>   problem.
>
> org.swift.common.cli.CliClient$RemoteDisallowedException: User
>   'FIRST.LAST@COMPANY.com' is not allowed to log in at this point in
>   time perhaps due to CAPTCHA requirements or too many failed login
>   requests. Go to the user interface and login to clear the problem. at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.helpers.AuthenticationHelper.login(AuthenticationHelper.java:196)
>   at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.helpers.AuthenticationHelper.login(AuthenticationHelper.java:157)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultAuthenticationHelper.handleCookies(DefaultAuthenticationHelper.java:124)
>   at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.getAuthenticationHelper(JiraClient.java:185)
>   at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.getAuthenticationHelper(JiraClient.java:107)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.setConnectionProperties(DefaultRequestHelper.java:1043)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.setConnectionProperties(DefaultRequestHelper.java:1030)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.makeRequestWithUrlConnection(DefaultRequestHelper.java:724)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.makeUrlRequest(DefaultRequestHelper.java:690)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.makeRequest(DefaultRequestHelper.java:660)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.DefaultRequestHelper.makeStandardRequest(DefaultRequestHelper.java:648)
>   at
>   org.swift.common.cli.helpers.AppfireRequestHelper.getServerInfo(AppfireRequestHelper.java:118)
>   at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.getRemoteServerInfo(JiraClient.java:2493)
>   at org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.getServerInfo(JiraClient.java:2455)
>   at org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.handleRequest(JiraClient.java:840) at
>   org.swift.common.cli.DefaultRemoteClient.process(DefaultRemoteClient.java:729)
>   at org.swift.common.cli.CliClient.doWork(CliClient.java:674) at
>   org.swift.common.cli.CliClient.doWork(CliClient.java:631) at
>   org.swift.jira.cli.JiraClient.main(JiraClient.java:166)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by creating an API token and using that as the password. You can create an API token by visiting the https://id.atlassian.com/ site and selecting the API tokens on the left pane.

I hope this helps.